# how to properly code a function to load asynchronously

Tags: javascript, random, colors, settimeout, asynchronous

i am trying to make a random color function load faster. currently the page loads everything on the page before it loads a random color div in the header. the function works, but it takes a long time to load. below is the current code for the random color function.

in the body tag is:

```
onload="return ran_col()" style="!important;"
```

in the body is a div with a script following it:

```
<div id="parallelogram" class="desktop-6 tablet-4 mobile-3">
<div id="logo" class="desktop-6 tablet-4 mobile-3">
<a href="/"><img src="{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}" style="border: 0;"></a>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ran_col() { //function name
var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
var letters = ['81ADB5','97C29D','E86A72','F1B36C', 'A37EA3', '277F92'];
color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
document.getElementById('parallelogram').style.background = color; }
</script>
```

i am trying to combine this function with a `setTimeout()` so the page loads the random color div immediately. below is an example i found in an article on [how to speed up your javascript](https://medium.com/@p_arithmetic/5-javascript-hacks-to-speed-up-your-javascript-acb44515497f):

```
var a = 3, b = 5;
function addNumbers (a, b) { 
return (a+b);
}
// this will run the code immediately
setTimeout('var c = addNumbers(a,b)', 1);
console.log(c);
```

i've tried several configurations, but i am new to javascript and am not having any luck accomplishing this. any suggestions on how to set this up properly? any advice would be greatly appreciated. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply imply your function into setTimeout:

```
 function ran_col() { //function name
    var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
    var letters = ['81ADB5','97C29D','E86A72','F1B36C', 'A37EA3', '277F92'];
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    document.getElementById('parallelogram').style.background = color; }

setTimeout(ran_col,1);
```

Comment: thank you for the speedy reply! that worked, but it also created another problem...now the div changes color twice in a single page load...once when the page first begins to load and once again when the page finishes loading. any advice on how to get the random color function to only change color once?

Comment: are you calling the ran_col() multiple times? how many times did you execute the function

Comment: not that i know of...i just have the one div in the body with the `ran_col()` ... the only thing i could think of is the header and footer are part of a theme page that draws content from an index page. i'm working in Shopify, so they have a theme.liquid page for the header and footer that pulls content from other pages. what do you think? any advice?

Comment: maybe if you have the link of the page i can have a look

Comment: i can share the link, but it is protected by a password...is there a secure way to send you the link and the password?

Comment: hmmm you can simply delete the comment of password after i see it or simply change password

Comment: you can delete it, now where is the problem ? where the problem happens?

Comment: Are you still Here @JesseHernandez I guess I found where is your problem I need to go soon

Comment: I figured it out...just had to remove the parenthesis from the onload command in the body tag. thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @JesseHernandez you shall remove onload="return ran_col()" from <body tag it is redundant